# Multi-page login - what is is for?

Tags: html, security, authentication

Some pages, such as amazon and Gmail, separate out the HTML Input fields for E-Mail and Password onto two different HTML pages, one after another.

What is the rationale for this approach instead of asking for credentials on just a single page with one HTML Form that has two Input fields at the same time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't programming related. It might be on-topic for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quentin I thought it was maybe security-related and thus relevant to programming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times this happens with federated identity, when multiple identity providers can actually log you in. For example you can use your company identity provider (ie. login server) to log onto a 3rd party resource which trusts your company IdP.

But the question is then how you choose which provider to use in the 3rd party, if they accept several. And this is one solution: you enter your email address, and your email is associated with your IdP, so you can be redirected to the correct login page (from where you will be redirected back). Of course, your IdP can easily be the site itself, in which case the process looks rather silly.

Note that you can be redirected to the "local" password page regardless of whether your username is actually correct or not, and usually only the domain part of the email is used to decide where to redirect, so it is less of a security issue, user enumeration is still not possible. But you can try and enumerate valid identity providers.